# A library with close can't create a new obj base on its constructor

Tags: javascript, closures

I received error of `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` on the line with `new`
it can only run if I do `var item =  mylib;`

However, I am not really clear what is the issue here.

```
(function(window){
    function mylib (){
        var Library={};
        Library.localVar1="One";
        Library.localVar2="Two";
        Library.func1 = function (){
            console.log("func1 output"+Library.localVar1)
            return true;
        }
        Library.func2 = function (){
            Library.func2Var1   = "func2One";
            console.log("func2 output"+Library.localVar2)
            return Library.func2Var1;
        }
        return Library;
    }
    //define globally if it doesn't already exist
    if(typeof(Library) === 'undefined'){
        window.mylib = mylib();
    }
    else{
        console.log("Library already defined.");
    }

})(window);

var item =  new window.mylib;
    console.log(item.localVar2,"var2");
    console.log(item.func2(),"func2");
    console.log(item.func1(),"func1");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use `var item =  new window.mylib;` I assume you want to create a new instance from `Library`.

But in your code, `Library` is an `Object`, not a constructor, constructor should be a `Function`. So you'll get that error.

```js
(function(window){
    function mylib (){
        var Library = function() {
          // Set self's variable
          this.localVar1="One";
          this.localVar2="Two";
        }
        
        // Use prototype to define the shared function.
        Library.prototype.func1 =  function (){
            console.log("func1 output"+this.localVar1)
            return true;
        };
      
        Library.prototype.func2 =  function (){
            Library.func2Var1   = "func2One";
            console.log("func2 output"+this.localVar2)
            return Library.func2Var1;
        };

        return Library;
    }
    //define globally if it doesn't already exist
    if(typeof(Library) === 'undefined'){
        window.mylib = mylib();
    }
    else{
        console.log("Library already defined.");
    }

})(window);

var item =  new window.mylib();  // Create a instance of Library
    console.log(item.localVar2,"var2");
    console.log(item.func2(),"func2");
    console.log(item.func1(),"func1");
```

Comment: btw, why we need to use prototype in this case? if I don't use it, what will be the difference?

Comment: In this case, you can set it to `this.func1 = ...`, no difference when showing, but use `this.func1...` will give every new `Library` object a distinct function, and when the number of `Library` object grows large, those functions cost more memories.

Comment: ah... so if we use prototype, the function in the new instance will always referencing back to the original ... library itself's func1 instead of creating a new func1 in the new instance itself. right?

Comment: Right,  you can also use `var sharedfunc1 = function()....` in that IIFE, then in constructor, `this.func1 = sharedfunc1 `, than all `Library` can now share the same `func1` too.